# Doctrine QueryBuilder and concat issues

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following code, which relies on Doctrine's QueryBuilder API to generate DQL statetements.

```
class PlayerRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findByPartialNameMatch($trainer, $fullName)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('tp');

        $qb->innerJoin('tp.player', 'p')
            ->where($qb->expr()->andX(
                    $qb->expr()->orX(
                        $qb->expr()->like(
                            $qb->expr()->concat('p.firstName', $qb->expr()->concat(' ', 'p.lastName')),
                            $qb->expr()->literal($fullName.'%')
                        ),
                        $qb->expr()->like(
                            $qb->expr()->concat('p.lastName', $qb->expr()->concat(' ', 'p.firstName')),
                            $qb->expr()->literal($fullName.'%')
                        )
                    ),
                    $qb->expr()->eq('tp.trainer', '?1')
                 )
             )
        ->groupBy('p.id')
        ->orderBy('p.lastName', 'ASC')
        ->orderBy('p.firstName', 'ASC')
        ->setParameter(1, $trainer);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

}

When I run it, Symfony2 throws the following error message:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 123: Error: Expected StateFieldPathExpression | string |      InputParameter | FunctionsReturningStrings | AggregateExpression, got ','
```

A look at the stack trace, reveals the following:

```
at QueryException ::syntaxError ('line 0, col 123: Error: Expected   StateFieldPathExpression | string | InputParameter | FunctionsReturningStrings |  AggregateExpression, got ','')
in D:\Work\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser.php at line 396  -+
at Parser ->syntaxError ('StateFieldPathExpression | string | InputParameter |  FunctionsReturningStrings | AggregateExpression')
in D:\Work\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser.php at line 2391  -+
at Parser ->StringPrimary ()
in D:\Work\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\ConcatFunction.php at line 60  -+
at ConcatFunction ->parse (object(Parser))
in D:\Work\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser.php at line 2852  -
```

From the above, I understand that the issue is somehow related to the concat helper function, and that the function expects the enumerated input but somehow(?) received a comma (,).

What is wrong with the code above? Hours of search could not shed a light into the problem.

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Thanks a lot, here my code:

`
$orX
   ->add(
       $this->qb->expr()->like(
           $this->qb->expr()->concat(
               "{$alias}.{$name}", 
               $this->qb->expr()->concat($this->qb->expr()->literal(' '), "{$alias}.{$lastname}"
)),
":v0"
)
)
`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The problem is about this part:

```
$qb->expr()->concat(' ', 'p.lastName')
```

You cannot just put space as doctrine expects some identificator here. Try this instead:

```
$qb->expr()->concat($qb->expr()->literal(' '), 'p.lastName')
```

Comment: Indeed it worked. The [Doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class), which provides an example about this, is inaccurate.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to share my concat code:

```
// It is easy to use array to project concat result. It will look like 'Diego Maradona Maradona Diego'
$concatFields = array(
    'p.firstName',
    'p.lastName',
    'p.lastName',
    'p.firstName',
);

// Routine code. All fields will be separated by ' '.
foreach ($concatFields as $field) {
    if (!isset($searchIn)) {
        $searchIn = $qb->expr()->concat($qb->expr()->literal(''), $field);
        continue;
    }

    $searchIn = $qb->expr()->concat(
        $searchIn,
        $qb->expr()->concat($qb->expr()->literal(' '), $field)
    );
}

// Just use concat result to search in.
$anyKeyword = 'ego';
$qb->add('where', $qb->expr()->like($searchIn, ':keyword'));
$qb->setParameter('keyword', '%'. $anyKeyword .'%');
```