# php orm powerful enough?

Tags: php, orm

I'm translating an application from MySQL to MSSQL, with statements written in db-specific SQL. Some of the statements involve `isnull()`, `ifnull()` and `concat()` which currently needs to be manually rewritten to MSSQL syntax.

To improve code portability I'm thinking of ORM alternatives which can solve the above, still with speed (I don't want the ORM to postprocess the result set).

Target databases:

- MySQL
- MSSQL
- PostgreSQL

Appreciate any hints or experiences in this matter.

Comment: use Doctrine http://www.doctrine-project.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that one of the best ORMs out there is Doctrine 2.

See the project website at http://doctrine-project.org/

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm new to ORM. But how does it work related to the question. Is the isnull, concat etc translated to snappy sql or is the ORM chewing data record by record?

Comment: ok, googled it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587578/doctrine-querybuilder-and-concat-issues Fair enough!

Answer (score 0):

I am using LLBLGen Pro http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLBLGen_Pro

The system is extensible so any third-party O/R mapper framework can be used in the designer